# Не пропадает контекстное меню

Tags: c#, wpf

Проблема в общем-то известная: при вызове контекстного меню, по нажатии везде кроме меню, оно остается "висеть".

```
private ContextMenu CMenu = (ContextMenu)this.FindResource("MyMenu");

private void MouseDown(object sender, WinForms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TrayMenu.IsOpen = true;
}
```

p.s: Пробовал и Activate() и Focus(), не помогло.

Answer (score 1):

А где у вас вызывается код типа

```
private void MouseUp(object sender, WinForms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TrayMenu.IsOpen = false;
}
```

да и вобще оно ведь как то с помощью конструктора назначается, зачем там код писать?

Comment: Тоже сначала думал, что проблема была в том, что событие добавляется и обрабатывается в коде класса.
Но нет, меню не убирается до первого показа окна! А по умолчанию Visibility = Hidden;